# Why netcat says that the host isn't authoritative?

Tags: hosts, netcat

When trying to establish a TCP connection to my IP address, `192.168.1.42`, **netcat** tells me that the *host isn't authorative*. That is,

```
[~] $ echo "Hello, world"|nc -c -vv 192.168.1.42 8080 & nc -l -p 8080 192.168.1.42
Warning: Host 192.168.1.42 isn't authoritative! (direct lookup mismatch)
  192.168.1.42 -> feross  BUT  feross -> 127.0.0.1
192.168.1.42 8080 (http-alt) open
Hello, world
Total received bytes: 0
Total sent bytes: 13
Total received bytes: 13
Total sent bytes: 0
```

Why?

Comment: Broken reverse DNS in a LAN? What does `host 192.168.1.42` report?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, `$ host 192.168.1.42` outputs `Host 42.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

Comment: OK, then `fgrep 192.168.1.42 /etc/hosts`

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, reports nothing

Comment: What do you try to achieve with `nc -c`?

Comment: Closing connection after "Hello World" has been sent. Not necessary though ...

Comment: What does your netcat(1) manual page say on `-c`? The thing you refer to is `-q` in my netcat.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi, nothing. I saw that option via `--help`: `-c, close connection on EOF from stdin`

Comment: I guess the message is coming from `-vv`. This makes it very verbose, so it prints optional reports like this.

Answer (score 1):

The message

```
Host 192.168.1.42 isn't authoritative! (direct lookup mismatch)
192.168.1.42 -> feross  BUT  feross -> 127.0.0.1
```

indicates that two specified BSD Sockets calls:

- gethostbyaddr – returns "feross" on 192.168.1.42 (IPv4)
- gethostbyname – returns 127.0.0.1 (IPv4) on "feross"

Assuming there is no 192.168.1.42 in `/etc/hosts` and `host 192.168.1.42` fails, it might be caused by broken setup in `/etc/host.conf`, by an obscure poorly documented name resolver library, or by whatever.